# Anyone else having issues with FolderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync on mobile?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-mobile, windows-10-universal

I believe there's a bug in FolderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync's implementation on Windows 10 mobile: calling that function seems to cause an error of some sort and stops normal code execution flow.

What makes it maddening, however, is that the incorrect behaviour occurs only when the app runs with no debugger attached, which makes figuring exactly what's going on difficult to say the least.

Consider the following code:

```
public async Task<bool> UserSelectFolderAsync()
{
    var picker = new FolderPicker();
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".");

    await ShowDialogAsync("Picking folder");
    var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    await ShowDialogAsync("Picked folder");

    if (folder == null)
        return false;

    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Clear();
    selectedFolder = folder;
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(selectedFolder);

    return true;
}

private async Task ShowDialogAsync(string message)
{
    MessageDialog showDialog = new MessageDialog(message);
    await showDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

**Update**

I have been investigating the issue further and I believe this is caused by the app being suspended while the user is interacting with the file picker.

On mobile, calling a picker means opening a different app, File Explorer, and setting that in the foreground, with the usual implications in terms of app lifecycle. I have been able to fairly reliably reproduce the issue on the emulator with debugger attached by:

1. Opening the file picker
2. Navigating to a location: onless I click on Device or SD card in the very first picker page the picker doesn't seem to take over as the foreground app
3. Suspending the app: from "Debug Location" toolbar click suspend button
4. Confirming the selection in the picker

In many cases, this causes whatever code follows the

```
await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

statement not to execute.

Unfortunately, while on Windows Phone 8 the way to deal with picker meant using

```
picker.PickFolderAndContinue();
```

and explicitly dealing with app suspension, doing so is no longer possible on Windows 10: calling the method above throws an exception.

Comment: Do you have something in *Suspending* or *EnteringBackground* (resuming and leaving) events?

Comment: No, I have nothing there

Comment: I tested with your code however I can't reproduce your issue. Have you tested in a real device? In Windows 10 the behavior of `FolderPicker` is different from what in Windows 8.1. There is no need to use `PickFolderAndContinue` method.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was calling

```
SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
```

in the `OnSuspending` event, when the app was suspended due to the file picker taking over.

This even if

```
SusendingDeferral.Complete();
```

was called immediately afterwards (no awaiting for operations to complete).

Ensuring a deferral is not requested when the app gets suspended due to the file picker has been enough to make the issue stop.